# Missing last value while counting number of data in each bin of histogram using java

Tags: java, arraylist, histogram, counting

Using below sample data :

```
List<Double> sampleData = Arrays.asList(1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11.);
```

We know the `binWidth` or `binSize` is 2 using the formula:

```
double binWidth = (max-min) / numberOfBins;
```

Where the `numberOfBins` are 5 using the Sturge’s formula:

```
int numbetOfBins = (int)Math.ceil((1.0 + (3.3 * (Math.log10(exampleData.size())))));
```

Now, I am trying to count the number of data in each bin of histogram. Using below code:

```
public void calculateBinsNumberOfData() {
    double binWidth = (max-min) / numberOfBins;
    System.out.println("Bin Width is: " + binWidth);
    double binMin = min, binMax, binDataPoints;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfBins; i++) {
        binMax = binMin + binWidth;
        binDataPoints = 0;
        for (Double double1 : sampleData) {
            if(double1 >= binMin && double1 <= binMax) {
                binDataPoints++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Bin "+i+" : ["+binMin+" to "+binMax+"] = " + binDataPoints);
        binMin = binMax;
    }
}
```

The output prints the results when including the last edge of a bin `double1 <= binMax` like:

[image: Number of data in each bin]

The output prints the results when not including the last edge of a bin `double1 < binMax` like:

[image]

And, you can observe in both above cases we are missing the value `11` of sample data. Now, I don't know how to fix this problem in this special case so that we can effectively count the last value of the data.